# Ansible nested json value extraction using json_query

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, json-query

I am looking for some to extract the value from a nested json when the condition is matching

Here you can see three different items are listed. I wanted to exact item value 
when the   `"target-name": "$variable"`

For example if  `"target-name": "dev-cn-c2"` then the item value will be `"item": "Standard"`

I tried json_query

```
results.results[?target-name==dev-cn-c2].item
```

and I am getting below response

```
[
  "PolicyPKG1",
  "PolicyPKG2",
  "Standard"
]
```

Please see the full json

```
{
    "results": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "checkpoint_access_layers": {
                        "access": true,
                        "access-layers": [
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "global domain",
                                    "name": "Global",
                                    "uid": "1e294ce0-367a-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9a66"
                                },
                                "name": "Network",
                                "type": "access-layer",
                                "uid": "b94c472e-56df-42f7-9c28-2b0b3d470657"
                            },
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "domain",
                                    "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                },
                                "name": "PolicyPKG1 Network",
                                "type": "access-layer",
                                "uid": "96ab580d-939a-476f-ac25-48782a1a4ed9"
                            }
                        ],
                        "color": "black",
                        "comments": "",
                        "desktop-security": false,
                        "domain": {
                            "domain-type": "domain",
                            "name": "dom-cn-1",
                            "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                        },
                        "icon": "Blades/Access",
                        "installation-targets": "all",
                        "meta-info": {
                            "creation-time": {
                                "iso-8601": "2019-07-30T15:38+0530",
                                "posix": 1564481316745
                            },
                            "creator": "admin",
                            "last-modifier": "admin",
                            "last-modify-time": {
                                "iso-8601": "2019-07-30T15:38+0530",
                                "posix": 1564481316745
                            },
                            "lock": "unlocked",
                            "validation-state": "ok"
                        },
                        "name": "PolicyPKG1",
                        "nat-policy": true,
                        "qos": false,
                        "qos-policy-type": "recommended",
                        "read-only": false,
                        "tags": [],
                        "threat-prevention": false,
                        "type": "package",
                        "uid": "231616b2-5ffa-4afe-9dcb-8fe1d0dd9ae3",
                        "vpn-traditional-mode": false
                    }
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "name": "PolicyPKG1",
                        "uid": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "PolicyPKG1"
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "checkpoint_access_layers": {
                        "access": true,
                        "access-layers": [
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "global domain",
                                    "name": "Global",
                                    "uid": "1e294ce0-367a-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9a66"
                                },
                                "name": "Network",
                                "type": "access-layer",
                                "uid": "b94c472e-56df-42f7-9c28-2b0b3d470657"
                            },
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "domain",
                                    "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                },
                                "name": "PolicyPKG2 Network",
                                "type": "access-layer",
                                "uid": "9651831a-7e9e-4a60-848f-ca4e194e2393"
                            }
                        ],
                        "color": "black",
                        "comments": "",
                        "desktop-security": false,
                        "domain": {
                            "domain-type": "domain",
                            "name": "dom-cn-1",
                            "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                        },
                        "icon": "Blades/Access",
                        "installation-targets": "all",
                        "meta-info": {
                            "creation-time": {
                                "iso-8601": "2019-07-30T15:38+0530",
                                "posix": 1564481331344
                            },
                            "creator": "admin",
                            "last-modifier": "admin",
                            "last-modify-time": {
                                "iso-8601": "2019-07-30T15:38+0530",
                                "posix": 1564481331344
                            },
                            "lock": "unlocked",
                            "validation-state": "ok"
                        },
                        "name": "PolicyPKG2",
                        "nat-policy": true,
                        "qos": false,
                        "qos-policy-type": "recommended",
                        "read-only": false,
                        "tags": [],
                        "threat-prevention": false,
                        "type": "package",
                        "uid": "d579c212-5486-4242-aa63-b510f6f3c93c",
                        "vpn-traditional-mode": false
                    },
                    "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "name": "PolicyPKG2",
                        "uid": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "PolicyPKG2"
            },
            {
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "checkpoint_access_layers": {
                        "access": true,
                        "access-layers": [
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "global domain",
                                    "name": "Global",
                                    "uid": "1e294ce0-367a-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9a66"
                                },
                                "name": "Network",
                                "type": "access-layer",
                                "uid": "b94c472e-56df-42f7-9c28-2b0b3d470657"
                            },
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "domain",
                                    "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                },
                                "name": "security",
                                "type": "access-layer",
                                "uid": "82d38fdf-11a1-4d2d-bc11-380aa922af1a"
                            },
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "domain",
                                    "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                },
                                "name": "Network",
                                "type": "access-layer",
                                "uid": "809bb6ce-2dbb-4e28-8bec-a6365999cdb5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "color": "black",
                        "comments": "",
                        "desktop-security": false,
                        "domain": {
                            "domain-type": "domain",
                            "name": "dom-cn-1",
                            "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                        },
                        "icon": "Blades/Access",
                        "installation-targets": "all",
                        "installation-targets-revision": [
                            {
                                "cluster-members-revision": [
                                    {
                                        "revision": {
                                            "domain": {
                                                "domain-type": "domain",
                                                "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                                "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                            },
                                            "name": "admin@4/30/2019",
                                            "type": "session",
                                            "uid": "1240db79-9cfa-4a29-b7f9-2b82fd915f4d"
                                        },
                                        "target-name": "dev-cn-c1",
                                        "target-uid": "84ed0d02-4a01-4079-90c2-b4a119e64cf2"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "revision": {
                                            "domain": {
                                                "domain-type": "domain",
                                                "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                                "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                            },
                                            "name": "admin@4/30/2019",
                                            "type": "session",
                                            "uid": "1240db79-9cfa-4a29-b7f9-2b82fd915f4d"
                                        },
                                        "target-name": "dev-cn-c2",
                                        "target-uid": "2639ab93-01ab-472c-a071-b24ad62eb49c"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "target-name": "Clus-01",
                                "target-uid": "7a5f9f5c-b533-4db6-b808-e8088ce6ab3c"
                            },
                            {
                                "cluster-members-revision": [
                                    {
                                        "revision": {
                                            "domain": {
                                                "domain-type": "domain",
                                                "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                                "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                            },
                                            "name": "admin@4/30/2019",
                                            "type": "session",
                                            "uid": "58b232f3-7826-40a7-b7f0-0e35985e999a"
                                        },
                                        "target-name": "dev-cn-4",
                                        "target-uid": "36289a7f-57ff-4320-bfe4-e7c640f3fdb1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "revision": {
                                            "domain": {
                                                "domain-type": "domain",
                                                "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                                "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                            },
                                            "name": "admin@4/30/2019",
                                            "type": "session",
                                            "uid": "58b232f3-7826-40a7-b7f0-0e35985e999a"
                                        },
                                        "target-name": "dev-cn-c3",
                                        "target-uid": "443a3649-65fe-4a7e-bf48-66973f239bf6"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "target-name": "Clus-cn-02",
                                "target-uid": "5a395d40-0615-4cde-9a39-5c024fc0278d"
                            }
                        ],
                        "meta-info": {
                            "creation-time": {
                                "iso-8601": "2019-04-26T16:31+0530",
                                "posix": 1556276469175
                            },
                            "creator": "System",
                            "last-modifier": "System",
                            "last-modify-time": {
                                "iso-8601": "2019-04-26T16:31+0530",
                                "posix": 1556276469175
                            },
                            "lock": "unlocked",
                            "validation-state": "ok"
                        },
                        "name": "Standard",
                        "nat-policy": true,
                        "qos": false,
                        "qos-policy-type": "recommended",
                        "read-only": false,
                        "tags": [],
                        "threat-layers": [
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "domain",
                                    "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                },
                                "name": "IPS",
                                "type": "threat-layer",
                                "uid": "5cab7f13-b376-4866-9b2d-1920ffc9a222"
                            },
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "domain-type": "domain",
                                    "name": "dom-cn-1",
                                    "uid": "9597dde5-6c2e-4696-a4b9-0e9c5118947a"
                                },
                                "name": "Standard Threat Prevention",
                                "type": "threat-layer",
                                "uid": "bcaa152e-f1d6-4c9e-aeee-4a5046abb061"
                            }
                        ],
                        "threat-prevention": true,
                        "type": "package",
                        "uid": "dc4d894f-8c77-41fc-bfd8-3a1a3c1335e2",
                        "vpn-traditional-mode": false
                    }
                },
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "name": "Standard",
                        "uid": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "Standard"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    - debug:
        var: results | json_query(query)
      vars:
        query: results[?ansible_facts.checkpoint_access_layers."installation-targets-revision"[?"cluster-members-revision"[?"target-name"=='dev-cn-c2']]].item
```

The query has been split out into a separate variable because string escaping in json_query is hard, and the hyphens (`-`) in the keys (for example `target-name`) messes things up a little.